# SQL : Get min and max with multiple iterations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get for this example table in MSSQL the min start and max stop grouped by activityid, dateid and personid.

The source table looks like the one below :

```
+--------+--------+------------------+------------------+------------+
| USERID | DATEID |      START       |       END        | ACTIVITYID |
+--------+--------+------------------+------------------+------------+
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 12:10 | 11/01/2021 12:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 12:15 | 11/01/2021 12:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 12:30 | 11/01/2021 12:45 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 12:45 | 11/01/2021 13:00 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 13:00 | 11/01/2021 13:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 13:15 | 11/01/2021 13:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 13:30 | 11/01/2021 13:45 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 13:45 | 11/01/2021 13:55 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 13:55 | 11/01/2021 14:00 | B          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 14:00 | 11/01/2021 14:05 | B          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 14:05 | 11/01/2021 14:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 14:15 | 11/01/2021 14:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 14:30 | 11/01/2021 14:45 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 14:45 | 11/01/2021 15:00 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 15:00 | 11/01/2021 15:10 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 15:10 | 11/01/2021 15:15 | C          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 15:15 | 11/01/2021 15:30 | C          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 15:30 | 11/01/2021 15:45 | C          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 15:45 | 11/01/2021 16:00 | C          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 16:00 | 11/01/2021 16:10 | C          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 16:10 | 11/01/2021 16:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 16:15 | 11/01/2021 16:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 16:30 | 11/01/2021 16:45 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 16:45 | 11/01/2021 17:00 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 17:00 | 11/01/2021 17:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 17:15 | 11/01/2021 17:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 17:30 | 11/01/2021 17:45 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 17:45 | 11/01/2021 18:00 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:00 | 11/01/2021 18:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:15 | 11/01/2021 18:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:30 | 11/01/2021 18:40 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:40 | 11/01/2021 18:45 | B          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:45 | 11/01/2021 18:50 | B          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:50 | 11/01/2021 19:00 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 19:00 | 11/01/2021 19:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 19:15 | 11/01/2021 19:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 19:30 | 11/01/2021 19:45 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 19:45 | 11/01/2021 20:00 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 20:00 | 11/01/2021 20:15 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 20:15 | 11/01/2021 20:30 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 20:30 | 11/01/2021 20:45 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 20:45 | 11/01/2021 21:00 | A          |
+--------+--------+------------------+------------------+------------+
```

The final result should be like this :

```
+--------+--------+------------------+------------------+------------+
| USERID | DATEID |      START       |       END        | ACTIVITYID |
+--------+--------+------------------+------------------+------------+
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 12:10 | 11/01/2021 13:55 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 13:55 | 11/01/2021 14:05 | B          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 14:05 | 11/01/2021 15:10 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 15:10 | 11/01/2021 16:10 | C          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 16:10 | 11/01/2021 18:40 | A          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:40 | 11/01/2021 18:50 | B          |
|      1 |      1 | 11/01/2021 18:50 | 11/01/2021 21:00 | A          |
+--------+--------+------------------+------------------+------------+
```

I have tried going with previous/next line values, but it would return only the previous line, being however unable to obtain the first and last.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is known as a "gaps and islands" problem; there's lots of examples of these on [so]. Have a look at those and you'll quickly find the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Will surely have to read more about this problem. It's great that I know what to search now, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gap-and-islands problem.  Assuming that adjacent values have no gaps, then the difference of row numbers is the simplest approach:

```
select userid, dateid, activityid,
       min(start), max(end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, dateid order by start) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, dateid, activity_id order by start) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, dateid, activityid, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by userid, dateid, min(start);
```

Note that `start` and `end` are very poor choices for column names because they are SQL keywords.  I assume your real names are safer.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly, I really have to dive deeper into this gap-and-islands concept. The columns are ok, I have only simplified the names here.